# How to prevent smoke detector from triggering while using my air fryer

Tags: frying

I'm using an air fryer to make things like potatoes, fish or carrots.

Every single time some amount of smoke (apparently oil) comes out of it and some almost translucent smoke probably from the food.

The annoying part is having the smoke detector being triggered every single time.

Any good tips to avoid this?

Thanks,

Comment: The "duplicated" answer is broad and general while this question is situational and specific to a the air fryer appliance and specific foods. I was hoping to find a simple useful answer like "use an oil with a higher smoke point, like avocado oil instead of olive oil"

Comment: Also, different foods have their own specific smoke points, like beef fat for example, claimed to be 400 F elsewhere. Do carrots and potatoes and fish have a smoke point lower than many cooking oils? This more specific question should be allowed to stand, to get specific answers.

Comment: I found that I have to place my air fryer really close to the extractor incorporated in the microwave. Seems like the air fryer has an output on the back and some oil was making it all the way to the smoke detector and triggering the fire alarm every single time. So, that worked for me, starting the cooking extractor fan and placing the air fryer just next to it did the trick.